# How do I determine which elements were changed in a django manytomanyfield

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a model with a ManyToManyField (*step*). I'd like to delete the objects (*ImagePlus*) linked to via this field if there is no *step* element referencing them anymore.

I tried to use the pre_delete signal and this works fine for half the problem (I can delete the referenced object if the last *step* referencing them is deleted).
However, I struggle to delete a referenced *ImagePlus* object if it is disconnected by an update to the manytomanyfield in a *step*.

I tried to solve it by overloading the save method or the pre_save/post_save signal of the *step* object, but the changes in the manytomanyfield are all either before or after either of those.

I also tried to solve it by interceping the m2m_changed signal of the through table.

Once more I can partially solve my problem. If I add/remove objects via .add or via .remove in the shell I get a proper post_add/post_remove signal that I can process like the delete one.

The problem here is that when I try to change the contents of the manytomanyfield in Django admin, or via ajax/DRF) I always get 4 signals in this order: 'pre_clear', 'post_clear', 'pre_add' and 'post_add'.
Now I cannot use the 'pre_clear' or 'post_clear' signals as I cannot know if the element is re-attached in a moment via an add signal. OTOH I cannot really use the 'pre_add' or 'post_add' signals as its not guaranteed that they will occur I think. (actually I am a bit confused why I don't get a single 'post_remove' signal instead of those 4 - would make life so much easier).

I tried this pre_clean/pre_add hack as shown below and it works reasonable. However, I am not sure about possible side effects. At least it seems dangerous and it will fail if only a clean is called without an add.

I am not really sure what my options are at this point. Make a timer that deletes the referenced objects if not reattached after 3 seconds? That would be quite clumsy and might cause database inconsistencies.

```
class Step(models.Model):
    instruments = ManyToManyField(ImagePlus, verbose_name="Instruments and materials", blank=True, related_name='instruments_step_set')
    previous_instruments = None

class ImagePlus(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(verbose_name="Single image", upload_to=CreateImageFilename('gallery/images'), null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Step)
def pre_delete_step(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for instrument in instance.instruments.all():
        if instrument.instruments_step_set.count()==1:
            instrument.delete()

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Step.instruments.through)
def m2m_changed_step(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    def cleanup (set):
        for element in set:
            if Step.instruments.through.objects.filter(imageplus__id=element).count()==0:
                ImagePlus.objects.get(id=element).delete()  

    if action == 'pre_clear':
        instance.previous_instruments = set(instance.instruments.all().values_list('pk',flat=True))
        instance.previous_instruments_timer = Timer (3, cleanup, (instance.previous_instruments,)) 
        instance.previous_instruments_timer.start()

    if action == 'pre_add':
        pk_set = kwargs.pop('pk_set', set())
        deleted = instance.previous_instruments-pk_set
        instance.previous_instruments_timer.cancel()
        instance.previous_instruments = None
        cleanup (deleted)

    if action == 'post_remove':
        deleted = kwargs.pop('pk_set', None)
        cleanup (deleted)
```

Comment: Just like pre_delete, you can use pre_save signal for the changes while updating.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. When calling via the admin interface first the pre/postsave signals from Step are called and only then the M2M field is modified at all. So I have no idea at that point what will be added/removed. When caling via AJAX its the other way around. First all actions are done for the M2M field and only then the pre/postsave signal of Step is called. Ok, here it could work if I duplicate the M2M field and do lots of custom work.

Comment: signals are called whenever you call `.save()` irrespective of there is any change or not.

Comment: Yes. But it is called like this: pre_save of Step. post_save of Step. pre_clean of ImagePlus. post_clean of ImagePlus. So when accessing the ImagePlus data from the pre_save/post_save signal I have no idea how the manytomanyfield looks after the change, do I?

Comment: One way out in that case is, passing the updates u're doing in save(), e.g. `save(updated_values=**updates)`

Comment: How would I do this for the admin and django rest framework so they send such an updated_values?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that I think is pretty stable by now by trying to save the old state in both the pre_save or the m2m_changed/pre_clear step and by encapsulating the post_save step in a transaction.on_commit clause. Any dangers with this one?

```
class Step(models.Model):
    instruments = ManyToManyField(ImagePlus, verbose_name="Instruments and materials", blank=True, related_name='instruments_step_set')
    previous_instruments = set()

class ImagePlus(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(verbose_name="Single image", upload_to=CreateImageFilename('gallery/images'), null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Step.instruments.through)
def m2m_changed_step_instruments(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'pre_clear':
        if instance.previous_instruments == set():
            instance.previous_instruments = set(instance.instruments.all().values_list('pk',flat=True))

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Step)
def pre_save_step(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.previous_instruments == set():
        instance.previous_instruments = set(instance.instruments.all().values_list('pk',flat=True))

@receiver(post_save, sender=Step)   
def post_save_step(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    def cleanup(stepid, old_instruments):
        step = Step.objects.get(id=stepid)

        for instrument in ImagePlus.objects.filter(id__in=old_instruments).exclude(id__in = step.instruments.all()).annotate(count=Count('instruments_step_set')).filter(count=0):
            instrument.delete()

    transaction.on_commit(lambda: cleanup(instance.id,instance.previous_instruments))

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Step)
def pre_delete_step(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for instrument in instance.instruments.all():
        if instrument.instruments_step_set.count()==1:
            instrument.delete()
```